# Hide QR barcode secret values

Tags: android, barcode, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have used ZXing barcode library in android project and everything is working fine for me

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(UserRegistered.this);
integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
```

And on activity result I have handled all my logic

This barcode scanner shows string values on screen but I want to put some secret inside the QR code and want return `SCAN_RESULT` value but not want to show it on screen.

How can I hide my secret data from end user while available to me as a `SCAN_RESULT`?

Comment: down-voter could you please explain reason for down vote? If you know better way to handle this situation, please do share it. It may be helpful to someone ?

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but probably because you should clarify what your requirements are. I guessed you don't need security, just obscurity. You didn't mention what you have tried either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, you could encode non-printable whitespace characters in the QR code, and somehow invent an encoding scheme using those types of chars that encodes something else. It would still be in plain sight in the data, but would not print because the extra chars are unprintable.

It's not a great solution, and isn't secure, but might be suitable for your use case.

Comment: Thanks @Sean ! yes this also can solve my problem. Still waiting for better answer :-)

Comment: Is it possible to hide the text shown on screen by editing your zxing library  ? or is there are ways to hide the text from end user ?

Comment: Sure but it would not change anything but what your custom build does.

Comment: could you please guide me what file/code exactly I have to edit? It's little bit difficult to me to find out.